# Build Multi-Param Query String

Tags: php

I am trying to build a multi-param query string, but I get a 500 error when I try to run this in production.  To me it get's quite difficult knowing where to place a `'` and a `"` but I am sure the more I php code the easier it will become.

Below is my syntax - what should be changed so that this becomes valid syntax? (all variables are declared in the script)

```
<td><a href="Test.php?emp='.$Row['Employee Name'].
'"&hiredate=" . $hiredate 
'"&terminationdate=" . $termdate 
'">'.$Row['Number Of Abscences'].'</a></td>
```

Comment: Just a thought - but try removing the single quote before `"&hiredate` and `"&terminationdate` - may not solve the issue, but worth a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use sprintf/vsprintf:

```
vsprintf('<td><a href="Test.php?emp=%s&hiredate=%s&terminationdate=%s">%s</a></td>',[$Row['Employee Name'],$hiredate,$termdate,$Row['Number Of Abscences']])
```

Is much more readable and easiet to maintain
\

Comment: And this is a snippet from a lengthy query string, I will use `vsprintf ` with the entire query string.  Thank you for letting me know about this.

Comment: If you are going to echo out a large table vsprintf is not always the easiest/best way to go IMHO

Comment: But is always better than mixing html+php in source code :) And we are talking now about creating simple link with anchor. If we have something bigger (much BIGGER) then we must remember about memory_limit, when we have to worry about miliseconds of execution time or worried about reaching max script execution time - we can looks for something faster/efficient. But for now? It's good enough, imho :)